# JQuery Working in Development, Not Production on Heroku Cedar

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

jQuery is working for me locally in development but not in production on Heroku Cedar. I'm very new to Rails, so I'm trying to learn this the right way rather than just slapping the code into a view. I don't see any errors in the server log. I'm compiling my assets locally with:

*bundle exec rake assets:precompile*

Then pushing the whole app to Heroku. I've tried several different gem combinations, current configuration:

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.2.2.0'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'
gem "friendly_id", "~> 4.0.9"
gem 'twitter'
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan'
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"
gem "cocaine", "= 0.3.2" 

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'thin'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: How so is it not working? Are there any JS errors that pop up (in your browser's development tools)? Also, try requiring jQuery before Bootstrap.

Comment: None of the jQuery interactions are working on the page. It loads fine though. There is one error, the first very long line of the application-xxxx.js file. Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: That Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function error will probably be what is stopping the rest of your javascript form working

Comment: Right, I think it's compiling Bootstrap before jQuery. How can I force it to do otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid error, I had an extra copy of bootstrap in my javascript assets folder. Once I removed that and recompiled the assets, everything worked as expected. No need for jQuery or bootstrap  files in your assets, just include the gems and the lines above in application.js, bootstrap after jQuery though.

Comment: Same error here 3 years later! You solution saved me! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case ,I'm just run theses commands:

- heroku run gem cleanup
- rake assets:precompile (locale)
- git push heroku master
  After this its works for me in rails 5