# Java script not working after precompile

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-sass

I've built a small site as a learning exercise and to give RoRs a go. I was pleased with the results in "dev" running against WEBrick but am having problems moving the site to "production" served via apache (so I can leave it around to look back on).

I've tried a number of small tweaks I've found but nothing seems to correct the problem - after I compile my assets JavaScript stops working - both my custom little jQuery and the built in bootstrap (drop downs) no longer works. The basic HTML is rendered correctly. I do appear to get one error in "application.js" visible in Chrome Developer tools. I feel this might be the problem but I haven't delved deep enough into the "asset pipeline" to catch it.

Can anyone spot where I might be going wrong?

Here are some details and happy to provide more if required. Would love to get this nailed down.

results of running a precompile:

```
$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
Ignoring `ruby` directive. This is a feature added to Bundler 1.2.0 and higher. Please upgrade if you would like to use it.

/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 /usr/local/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
$
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.1'
gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'json'
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.2.2.0'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
```

app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

app/assets/javascripts/rootEffects.js (some of my random jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Tooltips for gifts
  $('.edit').tooltip({'placement':'top'});
  $('.delete').tooltip({'placement':'top'});
  $('.tip-info').tooltip({'placement':'top'});
  $('.link-buy').tooltip({'placement':'bottom'});
  $('.long-name').tooltip({'placement':'top'});
});
```

Was going to provide the contents of public/assets/ but not sure if this would help.

Here are the errors I'm seeing via Chrome Dev tools. I'm disregarding the second error on the console as this is Chrome related.

[image: console error]

Below is the error shown if I click through from the console. I strongly feel this is related.

[image: JavaScript error]

From what I've read and understand - the precompile process is supposed to place all my JavaScript in a single file 'application.js' - possibly the error being thrown is stopping any of it being executed. So far, I haven't found a tweak to correct this so I'm reaching out for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awkward.

I must have played with my application.js in a different dir by accident.

I shifted around the entries again and voila it works (similar to this quesiton [JQuery Working in Development, Not Production on Heroku Cedar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758585/jquery-working-in-development-not-production-on-heroku-cedar))

Final application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 0):

if your JavaScript not work than add following line to production.rb file

```
config.assets.compile = ['*.js', '*.css']
```